# Certainty of data distribution profile when performing a sort operation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, probability

Lets assume we have some data structure like an array of n entries, and for arguments sake lets assume that the data has bounded numerical values .

Is there a way to determine the profile of the data , say monotonically ascending ,descending etc to a reasonable degree, perhaps with a certainty value of z having checked k entries within the data structure?

Comment: How are the values in your list of n numbers distributed? IID Uniform(0, 1)?

Comment: That is an interesting addition, can you define a probability algorithm to determining the data profile assuming different distribution probabilities

Comment: It's actually not even an addition - to say "certainty" of something, it must be probabilistic. I am thinking about this problem...might come back with an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have an array of size N, this means that we have  N-1 comparisons between each adjacent elements in the array. Let M=N-1. M represents the number of relations. The probability of the array not being in the correct order is

```
1/M
```

If you select a subset of K relations to determine monoticallly ascending or descending, the theoretical probability of certainty is

```
K / M
```

Since these are two linear equations, it is easy to see that if you want to be .9 sure, then you will need to check about 90% of the entries.

This only takes into account the assumptions in your question. If you can are aware of the probability distribution, then using statistics, you could randomly check a small percentage of the array.

If you only care about the array being in relative order(for example, on an interval from [0,10], most 1s would be close to the beginning.), this is another question altogether. An algorithm that does this as opposed to just sorting, would have to have a high cost for swapping elements and a cheap cost for comparisons. Otherwise, there would be no performance pay offs from writing a complex algorithm to handle the check.

It is important to note that this is theoretically speaking. I am assuming no distribution in the array.

Comment: Your selection of the subset is taking the entire interval I assume ? What about probing the data structure when not using one single discrete interval , ie in checking say a 100 array , if one wanted to check for 60% chance of it being monotonically increasing without check values 1-60 , but rather some other arbitrary access pattern?

Comment: This analysis is not right. If I have 2 numbers in a list, where numbers are IID as Uniform(0, 1), you're saying that I can look at 50% of the values to be sure the values are monotonically ascending. If I look at only the second number and see it has value 0 <= p <= 1, then there is a probability of p that the values are monotonically ascending - not a probability of 0.5.

Comment: Each relation is independent. Making no assumptions, it does not matter whether you choose a straight interval or random indexes. The probablity will be the same because each relation does not influence the probability to the next. @Timothy The general math stands to be true, but I was a little unclear. N and K represent the relations(a<b is a relation). In 2-length array, you test one relation, then you have tested 100% (1/1). I edited the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The easier problem is to check the probability of encountering such orderly behavior from random data.

Eg. If numbers are arranged randomly there is p=0.5 that the first number is lower than the second number (we will come to the case of repetitions later). Now, if you sample k pairs and in every case first number is lower than second number, the probability of observing it is 2^(-k).

Coming back to repetitions, keep track of observed repetitions and factor it in. Eg. If the probability of repetition is q, probability of not observing repetitions is (1-q), probability of observing increasing or equal is q + (1-q)/2, so exponentiatewith k to get the probaility.